# JS. Создать массив из 20 случайных числел в диапазон от – 100 до 100

Tags: javascript

Создать массив из 20 случайных чисел в диапазон от – 100 до 100. Вывести их на экран. При помощи функции filter – создать массив в котором останутся только числа, которые > 0 (тоже вывести на экран)

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, с какой проблемой вы столкнулись при решении этой задачи. И добавьте в впорос код вашего (пусть и не полного) решения.

Answer (score 0):

Создать массив из 20 случайных чисел в диапазон от – 100 до 100:

```
let array = []
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    array.push(-100 + Math.random() * ((100 - (-100)) + 1))
}
```

а дальше создаете функцию в которой в цикле проверяете если текущее значение массива >0, то заносите его в новый массив